# Passing values to intent with JSON

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am trying to pass value using Newtonsoft.Json from shared project to droid project. So in my shared project i am serializing the object as follows and getting certain result, also displayed below. Then i am taking that result to droid project and trying to deserialize value however i am getting an exception also displayed below

**My Project**

```
 public void PushDictionary(List<Word> allWordsOfUserForAutomat)
        {
            var second = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance, typeof(LockScreenDictionary));
           
            second.PutExtra("MyData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allWordsOfUserForAutomat));
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allWordsOfUserForAutomat);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(second);
        }
```

Outcome of my result from json here is "`[{\"Id\":3391,\"SentenceId\":40616,\"TextEng\":\"expensive\",\"Explanation\":\"expensive (price)\",\"GrammarDetail\":null,\"DateToShow\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}]"`

**My droid**

```
  var allWordsOfUserForAutomat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Word>(Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData"));
            List<Word> _allWordsOfUserForAutomat = null;
            _allWordsOfUserForAutomat.Add(allWordsOfUserForAutomat);
            LangUpDictionaryPlayer.PlayAutomat(_allWordsOfUserForAutomat);
```

However i am getting this exception, can someone please advise me

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'AT.Model.Word' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are serializing a LIST of words

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allWordsOfUserForAutomat);
```

then you are trying to deserialize a SINGLE word

```
var allWordsOfUserForAutomat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Word>(Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData"));
```

instead, deserialize a LIST

```
var allWordsOfUserForAutomat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Word>>(Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData"));
```

note that the exception tells you **exactly what to do** to fix this

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) or **change the deserialized type to an array or a
> type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
> like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.**